# spring cloud rabbitmq not create queues when i add spring-boot-starter-web-services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

i'm working on a sample in github on this [repository](https://github.com/amiraziz/spring-stream-rabbitMq).

this project worked correctly and all queues in three modules (producer, process, consumer) automatically create until i add this dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${open-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>${open-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I debug that for long time and only I found is before adding this dependencies, when the program reached to first line in `FunctionConfiguration#FunctionToDestinationBinder#afterPropertiesSet`,  bean of `BindableProxyFactory` class was detected and my bindings in produce(`receiveResponse`) create after it. but after i add `spring-boot-starter-web-services`,  bean of `BindableProxyFactory` is empty and naturally no queue is created.

can anyone know what is conflicting beans between `spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit` and `spring-boot-starter-web-services`?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

after debug in separated times, i found this property `spring.cloud.function.definition` located in `FunctionConfiguration#FunctionBindingRegistrar#determineFunctionName` and after adding that in producer config, queue was created.

base on [this document of spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html), you can use multiple definition with `;` splitter like this `spring.cloud.function.definition=recieve;sendMessage`